# NoSQL и поиск данных

Tags: база-данных, nosql

На днях начал вникать в NoSQL, по своим причинам использую LevelDB. Никак не могу понять, если у меня есть около 5000 записей в виде объекта с именем и некоторым интовым значением. Как мне, например, получить 100 записей в топе? Неужели приходится самому организовывать такие моменты взаимодействия с базой данных?

Comment: Во-первых, LevelDB написан на C++, го тут вообще ни при чём. Во-вторых, NoSQL-базы данных как раз такие быстрые за счёт ограничения функциональности. Если вам нужна однофайловая БД с нормальными запросами, используйте SQLite.

Comment: LevelDB может быть написана на чем угодно. Ничто не мешает имплементировать её на любой другой язык, на go есть своя неофициальная имплементация полностью идентичная той, что на C++. SQLite оставляет желать лучшего, грузит одно ядро и не справляется